# extracting currency values using scrapy/xpath

Tags: scrapy

Trying to get currency values from some html using scrapy.Code is

```
links = hxs.select('//a[@class="product-image"]/div[@class="price-box"]//span[@class="price"]/text()').extract()')
```

And the HTML

```
<div>
  <span>
    <sub>
      <li class="item first">

        <a href="http://www.xtra-vision.ie/dvd-blu-ray/to-rent/new-release/dvd/pitch-perfect-dvd.html" title="Image for Pitch Perfect" class="product-image">

          <span class="exclusive-star">
          </span>

          <img src="http://www.xtra-vision.ie/media/catalog/product/cache/3/small_image/124x173/5b02ab93946615b958c913185aae2414/i/w/iws_5167c10c906b57.33524324.JPG.jpg"  alt="Image for Pitch Perfect" />

          <h2 class="product-name">Pitch Perfect</h2>

          <div class="price-box">

            <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-5174">

              <span class="price">
                €15                     
                <sub class="price-bit">.99</sub>
              </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </sub>

  </span>

</div>
```

The resulting price i get is \u20ac15\t\t\t\t\t\t
Is there some way I can extract  15.99 from this html using xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a combination of xpath and Python so might not be quite what you were after, although this was mainly employed to get rid of the extraneous tabs added to the end of the "price".

```
price = hxs.select('//span[@class="price"]/text()').extract()
pricebit = hxs.select('//span[@class="price"]/sub[@class="price-bit"]/text()').extract()
totalprice = price + price-bit
totalstr = ''.join(totalprice).replace('\t','')
```